# Would uninstalling Gedit be detrimental? (18.10)

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, gedit

I, after installing the MATE and Cinnamon desktops to my system, got Pluma recently, which is working far faster and easier for me on this computer. My question is simple; would uninstalling Gedit be an issue?

From what I've seen there are conflicting thoughts on if Gedit will interrupt `ubuntu-desktop` in some way. Either it uninstalls key components, only `gedit`, or `ubuntu-desktop` entirely-- but none of these are full confirmations, and most are heavily outdated (going back to 9.10). I might not use Ubuntu Desktop, but I know that a lot of Ubuntu core packages require it.

**Would it be detrimental in any way to my system to uninstall Gedit?**

Comment: Run a simulation: `apt purge -s gedit` to see what else will be removed. You don't need `sudo`.

Comment: You have that backwards, no package 'requires' the ubuntu-desktop package. The ubuntu-desktop  meta package depends and recommends on many packages itself and is required only for a release upgrade. (which you'll need or should  do shortly

Comment: Have you uninstalled either GNOME, Unity, or both?

Comment: the system this was written about has since been abandoned, but it was Ubuntu 18.10 Unity i believe